# Parsing XML in C# having json in attribute

Tags: c#, xml, parsing

I have an XML like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<Elements xmlns="http://sample.com/">

<ServerSideComponent 
    Name="SQL" 
    Id="100"    
    ComponentManifest=
        "{
        "id":"101",
        "componentType":"AnyType",
        "supportedHosts":["Win","Mac","Android","Linux"]
        }">
</ServerSideComponent>
</Elements>
```

I want to parse componentType and supportedHosts from it.
How can I do that in c#?
I tried GetElementsByTag / GetAttributes, but not able to do it. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: That's not valid XML, you're using double quotes in double quotes so it breaks parsing.

Comment: Agree the XML is malformed.  Upload it to https://www.xmlvalidation.com/ and you will get an error, ***`10:11 Element type "ServerSideComponent" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".`***

Comment: The XML is malformed for two issues.  You have an attribute ComponentManifest which has double quotes inside double quotes.  You also have an extra closing angle bracket which is not needed at the end of the attribute ComponentType.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your comments.
After going through the original file, I sew that " were replaced with "
And the manifest validation passed

Here is the working code:

```
            XmlDocument xmldoc = new XmlDocument();
            xmldoc.Load(@"C:\Users\abc\file.xml");

            // Select nodes by TagName
            XmlNodeList nodeList = xmldoc.GetElementsByTagName("ServerSideComponent");
            foreach (XmlNode node in nodeList)
            {
                var Name = node.Attributes["ComponentManifest"].Value;
                dynamic stuff = JObject.Parse(Name);
                Console.WriteLine("supportedHosts: ");

                foreach (string host in stuff.supportedHosts)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(host);

                }

                var componentType = stuff.componentType;
                Console.WriteLine("Component Type = " + componentType);
            }
```